# I can't tell the difference between the area of where and the area where

Tags: relative-clauses, indirect-question, where

### Conservation: a People Centred Approach
By Francis Gilbert, Hilary Gilbert

> The impact of climate change on animals and plants interacts with habitat loss and fragmentation. This is because the main effect of climate change is to shift **the area of where** any one species can live successfully. In a warming world, this habitable space moves either polewards across the landscape, to the North or South, or up in elevation, with species living higher up mountains than ever before. This happens because the area where the mean temperature is 15°C, for example, shifts in these directions under global warming. Survival then depends on whether a particular species can move, and if so, whether there is a suitable pathway for the movements to happen. Neither of these things can be assumed, and where habitats become too fragmented, a suitable pathway for organisms to move to other areas becomes less of a realistic possibility.
>
> — *[Conservation: a People Centred Approach](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YGOtDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=The+impact+of+climate+change+on+animals+and+plants+interacts#v=onepage&q=The%20impact%20of%20climate%20change%20on%20animals%20and%20plants%20interacts&f=false),* Francis Gilbert/Hilary Gilbert,  OUP 2019

Q. I want to know the difference between A and B.
A : This is because the main effect of climate change is to shift the area of where any one species can live successfully.

B : This is because the main effect of climate change is to shift the area where any one species can live successfully.

- My research

Searching for where usage From Cambridge

1. Where as a relative pronoun
   The hotel **where** we spent our honeymoon has been demolished.
2. We can use where in indirect questions:
   I asked him **where** I could buy an umbrella.

Comment: Omit _of_;  the rest of the sentence is OK. _Where_ is a relative pronoun, and _where clause_ is a relative clause.

Comment: I think the writing is not of the highest caliber and you should not think too deeply on why the author chose to do anything.

Comment: @dongyoungkim Please note the edit to your question to mark a quote as a quote and provide a citation. It's important to know when and where a text was published and by whom it was written. You may need to update some of your other questions.

Comment: Okay... I didn't know that sorry... I will do it as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm not happy with it. I'd expect 'the area/s where' or 'boundaries of where'.

Comment: We wouldn't *usually* include that superfluous ***of***, but [it's far from unknown.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22area+of+where%22) I wouldn't call it an "error" - just a very uncommon stylistic choice that should probably always be avoided.

Comment: I have voted to reopen because I find the comments too focussed on grammatical supposition and stylistic opinion and too little focussed on meaning and context to justify closure of a question that is now precisely referenced and reasonable.

Comment: On reading this again I strongly advocate reopening. The meaning and usage are not matters of mere opinion as the closers assume. The answer depends at least on the definition of “of”, as I tackled in my own answer. They may also depend on other issues and it would be useful to hear others’ views.

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings of “of” is

> typical or characteristic of
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)

As the author embarked on their train of thought, they wished to distinguish between an area that can move and one that cannot.

For example, the area within the Swiss frontiers is presently fixed, whereas the area occupied by the flower species Edelweiss may move according to climate change and shifting management regimes.

Hence it is reasonable to refer to the area “where the Edelweiss presently grows” but to refer to the area **of** (= typical or characteristic of) “where it might grow”.

The distinction is small but useful in discussing how stationary or slowly moving areas of living species interact with faster moving zones characterised by crucial climate or mini-climate.

Comment: I understand your point and it appears to be a nuanced answer, except that you've not touched upon the grammatical validity of the construction _[area] of where...._ What is the syntax of this construction? @Anton

Comment: The writer could have chosen _locale/location_, instead of resorting to using a possibly syntactically unsound construction.

Comment: @user405662 I am loth to attempt authoritative grammatical analysis, being no grammarian. However it seems to me there may be an element of ellipsis here. “… the area of where” = “… the area typical or characteristic of where…” Or perhaps one should just accept that the author uses *of* in the quoted Cambridge sense?

Answer (score -1):

I doubt the author thought of the expression

***live off (of) (someone or something)***

> To survive by eating or drinking something, especially exclusively or
> very frequently.
>
> - A species of insect lives off this weed, so if it is
>   eliminated completely, the insects will die, too.

([FreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+off+of))

or

> They had learned to live off the land.

([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/live-off-sb-sth))

But if that were the case, then the use of ***where*** after *off* would not be successful, one might want to use ***off which*** rather.

So that makes it clear that it is a mistake, ***of*** should not be there.

Comment: I believe that the author is too competent in their ecological knowledge and too precise In the way they express these conventional  ecological notions for us to attribute such an error to them.  No contemporary ecologist discussing fragmented habitat and pathways for the flora  would be thinking of species living “off” the land. Even less would they write academically in that vein. I doubt that they would do so for fauna. As the rest of the quoted material makes clear, this is all about the issue of species survival within the changing patterns of where life could or could not exist.

Comment: Yes, agreed. "live off" does not belong to the register the author uses.